# Install Flash Player on Firefox w/o admin access?

Tags: firefox, installation, flash-player, non-admin

Say, juys.

I'd really like a way to install Adobe Flash Player 10 (or latest version) on Firefox 3 without having admin access in a corporate environment. Because I'm a limited user, I can't do the install myself with or without Adobe Download Manager. Is there any way to accomplish this, anyone?

Should I try something like Portable Apps maybe?

Thanks very much!

Comment: you should contact your IT department with your wishes rather than trying to circumvent their security policies with help from the outside. and my fellow forum mebers should refrain from participating in such actions for the sake of the reputation of superuser.com

Comment: It is possible but as Molly said you should talk with your IT department. Likely if they have domain policies to stop you from installing it there is a reason. Even if you did manage to install it there is a good chance they will know so you may want to just ask.

Comment: If you use Portable Apps, you won't be installing anything on the computer, so that probably won't violate your IT department's policy.

Answer (score 2):

[How-To-Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/install-flash-plugin-manually-in-firefox-on-vista/) had an article about installing Flash 9 in FireFox manually. Follow the steps to install into your profile not the All Users profile, as that will probably be locked down by the Corporate IT Department. I haven't tested it with Flash 10 myself.

I would warn however that your IT department may well frown upon installing Flash 10 this way. Depending on the organisations policies, manually installing software could be breaking the companies Acceptable Use Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you use a [portable version of firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) you can install any plugins / addons you need since the directory structure is self-contained in a way that you will have full permissions.