# Installing Flash for Firefox on OSX without admin rights

Tags: macos, firefox, installation, flash, non-admin

I have installed a local copy of Firefox in my folder without admin rights. Is there a way to install Flash for it as well without admin rights? I have found instructions for Windows [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/install-flash-plugin-manually-in-firefox-on-vista/) and [here](http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/installing%20flash%20player%20plugin%20firefox%20without%20having%20administrator%20access%20or%20premissions).

My related question: [Where is the Mozilla Firefox plugins folder on a Mac](https://superuser.com/q/379239/72590)

Earlier question on SU for Windows: [Install Flash Player on Firefox w/o admin access?](https://superuser.com/q/63237/72590)

Answer (score 0):

With most apps the "installer" is just a .dmg file and if you open this and it just says to drag to applications you can drag it somewhere else for example your desktop. If the file is a .pkg then you do need admin rights to install it.